# Server Status Checker in real time

Tags: php, html, server, status

I managed to display the status of a server using FSOCKOPEN.

```
<?php
    $ip = "0.0.0.0";
    $port = "1337";
    $online = '<font class="online" title="Server Online!">ONLINE</font>';
    $offline = '<font class="offline" title="Server Offline!">OFFLINE</font>';
if (! $sock=@fsockopen($ip, $port, $num, $error, 0.25))
    {echo "$offline";}
else
    {echo "$online";}
?>
```

If the server with the IP "0.0.0.0" sends an error or does not respond within 1/4th of a second after the page has been loaded the Output will return OFFLINE, else it will return ONLINE.

The server status will update when the user refreshes the page.

Now I want to make it to update in real time (less than 7 seconds delay)

I know there is a very easy method to do that using `<meta http-equiv=”refresh” content=”5" />` in the head tag.

But its pretty annoying that the COMPLETE page have to refresh and load everything again and its causing some unnecessary traffic.

Is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ajax and javascript in the client to open the PHP Script in the background and then update the element in the page with the result based on success/failure.

Take a look at `jQuery` and other library to do this easily.

Another option would be a simple `<iframe />` to open another website as an element on the website.

Comment: I already used iframes before. Its just like the other one with the traffic. Additionally i want to have a status that doesn't interrupt while loading which happens at http refreshes or iframe refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use ajax or any direct polling mechanism that will put more load on your server in terms of traffic.

What you can use is websockets to push data to a stream and read it in frontend

https://socket.io/

This can be done near realtime and your page will not be reuired to get updated every min.

Put PHP script in cron to run at required interval and end of it just push the output to sockets and catch them on frontend.

Comment: Web sockets are only required when there is bi-directional communication.  Server-sent events (SSE) would be better here.